# How to switch view via click the UIBarButtonItem in UINavigationController, in Storyboard?

Tags: ios5, storyboard

I want to display some data in two mode, so via click the UIBarButtonItem which is named "switch" in UINavigationControlle.

I can do it using Storyboard and xib, **but I just want to know how to implement it only using Storyboard.**

*using Storyboard and xib:*
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ViewControllerOne.h"
#import "ViewControllerTwo.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ViewControllerOne *view1 = [[ViewControllerOne alloc] init];
    ViewControllerTwo *view2 = [[ViewControllerTwo alloc] init];

    [self.view insertSubview:view1.view atIndex:1];
    [self.view insertSubview:view2.view atIndex:0];
}

- (IBAction)switchButton:(id)sender
{
    [self.view exchangeSubviewAtIndex:0 withSubviewAtIndex:1];
}
```

*If I only using Storyboard and the code like above, then nothing happened, the view just is empty:*
[image]

Answer (score 0):

why not just use the seque in storyboard without code. That will be simply and enough

Comment: 而且可以，默认load第一个view，点按钮就push到第二个，然后再用unwind返回啊

Comment: 我也是新学这个，做了个简单的demo，不知道是不是你想要的那样。。留个邮箱发给你吧

Comment: unwind 原来是ios 6的新东西。不过我用的是ios 5，换方案了，其实直接pop一下也可以了。